программа отказывается работать, PyCharm указывает ,что дело в cap.read() ,но я не понимаю, что не так
import cv2
"""
img = cv2.imread("images/II.jpg")

cv2.imshow("123", img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
"""

fig =  cv2.VideoCapture('vidos/more.mp4')

while True:
    fgh, arm = 
    cv2.imshow("res", arm)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & ord("q") == 0xFF:
        break


Ошибка:
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\python.ii\ii.1\.venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\python.ii\ii.1\main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\python.ii\ii.1\main.py", line 13, in <module>
    fgh, arm = cap.read()
               ^^^
NameError: name 'cap' is not defined. Did you mean: 'map'?

Process finished with exit code 1


всё, я сам разобрался

если сам разобрался, то вопрос можно удалить.

Ну или ответить, чтобы помочь другим людям с такой же проблемой.

Приведённый код и ошибка явно друг-другу не соответствуют.

import cv2
"""
img = cv2.imread("images/II.jpg")

cv2.imshow("123", img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
"""

fig =  cv2.VideoCapture('vidos/more.mp4')

while True:
    fgh, arm = ''#исправлено
    cv2.imshow("res", arm)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & ord("q") == 0xFF:
        break

вот так

пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
